# How to set codemirror to highlight multiple languages in Django admin?

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin, codemirror

For one of my pet projects, I needed to use syntax highlighting for one of the TextField fields. **Codemirror** is great for this. After trying several “django-batteries” with widgets, I decided to abandon external dependencies and install codemirror myself.

Models have `TbTemplate` with fields for describing templates. From there, the backend takes templates for rendering, and the `TextField` itself with the template is `szJinjaCode`.

I do it like this.

#### admin.py:

```py
class TemplateAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TbTemplate
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            'szJinjaCode': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'jinja2-editor'})
        }


# Template admin
@admin.register(TbTemplate)
class AdminTemplate(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        # set for codemirror ON
        css = {
            'all': (
                # '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/doc/docs.css',
                '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/lib/codemirror.css',
                '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/hint/show-hint.css',
                '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/lint/lint.css',
                '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/theme/rubyblue.css',
            )
        }
        js = (
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/lib/codemirror.js',
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/hint/show-hint.js',
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/hint/xml-hint.js',
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/hint/html-hint.js',
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/mode/xml/xml.js',
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/mode/javascript/javascript.js',
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/mode/css/css.js',
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js',
            '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/mode/jinja2/jinja2.js',
            # '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/runmode/colorize.js',
            # '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/hint/html-hint.js',
            # '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/lint/lint.js',
            # '/static/codemirror-5.65.13/addon/lint/html-lint.js',
            '/static/js/codemirror/init_jinja2.js'
        )

    # set form TemplateAdminForm
    form = TemplateAdminForm
    # other description for admin TbTemplate
    # ...
    # ...
```

As you can see from the code, you also need to run the initialization file `/static/js/codemirror/init_jinja2.js` into statics-files. Actually, he took from the recipe and changed it a little:

#### /static/js/codemirror/init_jinja2.js

```
(function(){
    var $ = django.jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.jinja2-editor').each(function(idx, el){
            function getSelectedRange() {
                return { from: editor.getCursor(true), to: editor.getCursor(false) };
            }
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(el, {
                lineNumbers: true,
                tabSize: 2,
                // mode: 'text/html',
                mode: 'text/jinja2',
                gutters: ['CodeMirror-lint-markers'],
                theme: 'rubyblue',
                lint: true,
            });
            CodeMirror.commands["selectAll"](editor);
            var range = getSelectedRange();
            editor.autoFormatRange(range.from, range.to);
            range = getSelectedRange();
            editor.commentRange(false, range.from, range.to);
        });
    });
})();
```

We start, and everything works. The highlighting of Jinja2-tags and variables works more precisely. If you change `mode: 'text/jinja2'` to `mode: 'text/html'` in `init_jinja2.js`, the html-code will be highlighted, but the Jinja2-markup will not be highlighted... I want both codes to be highlighted. Even better if you also highlight CSS, JavaScript and JSON. How to make codemirror highlight it all at the same time?

**P.S.** The option suggests itself -- to take the necessary “mod” files from the `/static/codemirror-5.65.13/mode/` directory into *codemirror* and assemble your own “mode” from them, but this is a crippling solution for codemirror itself. When it is codemirror-updated, everything will collapse and this home-made “mod” will have to be reassembled. This, it seems to me, is wrong. I would like to turn on several “mod” (backlight modes) at the same time in a regular way. How?